# How to handle date format with DateTimePicker and knockout-observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, datetimepicker, date-format

I am struggling with datetimepicker and data formatting.
My date time is stored in this format: "`yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss.000`".

If I'm not formatting, my date datetimepicker misprints it. If I *do* format it, I get an error from my bindingHandlers:

> [Error] TypeError: 09.04.2016 19:24:48 is not a function (evaluating 'observable($(element).val())')

I feel like I'm catching some deadlock here, but surely there must be a way around it?

HTML:

```
<input  type="text" data-bind="datetimepicker:viewWhenDateTime,datetimepickerOptions:{dateFormat:'dd.mm.yy',timeFormat:'HH:mm:ss',addSliderAccess:true,sliderAccessArgs:{touchonly:false}}" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function ViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.whenDateTime = ko.observable("2016-04-09T19:24:48.000");
   self.viewWhenDateTime = self.whenDateTime().parseDate();
}
```

BindingHandlers:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datetimepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datetimepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).val());
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datetimepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        current = $(element).val();
        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $(element).datetimepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/nrsathdg/

Answer (score 1):

Your binding handler is two-way: it'll try to update the thing passed to it as if it were an observable. *However*, your `viewWhenDateTime` bound to it is *not* observable.

Given that

1. `viewWhenDateTime` is dependent on another observable; and
2. `viewWhenDateTime` will be bound using a two-way binding handler

you'll probably need a writeable observable.

Something along these lines:

```
function ViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.whenDateTime = ko.observable("2016-04-09T19:24:48.000");
   self.viewWhenDateTime = ko.computed({
     read: function() { return self.whenDateTime().parseDate(); },
     write: function(newVal) {
       // Do the inverse of `parseDate` here
       // and set it to self.whenDateTime(....)
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jeroen! 
I´m getting close but I get a binding error: Message: Unable to process binding "datetimepicker: function (){return viewWhenDateTime }"
Message: invalid date.

This seems to happen before I enter the write-part of the computable.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you should try to isolate that issue and consider asking a seperate question about it. It seems to be an issue with `parseDate` for which you haven't provided the code, and may be an issue on itself?

Comment: you might be right. However to me it looks like the whenDateTime gets truncated by the bindingHandler. In the fiddle the time-part is never show. Hence the "inverseparseDate" fails due to the "newVal" just being a data with a blank after. Any idea why the truncation happen? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/p7Ljmdny/